# regex python - trying to find specific characters with spaces in a line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
line = 'Index        : 1080                   IP Addr      : X.X.X.X'
```

Finding if `'Index'` with the `':'` appears in this line. Do the following - 
`'Index+\s+\:'` in line

What is incorrect in the above regex? It returns a false

Comment: Show your code not just your regular expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I find https://regex101.com/ useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches the given line:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'Index        : 1080                   IP Addr      : X.X.X.X'
>>> re.match(r'Index+\s+:', line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x022DE758>
```

However, the `+` after the `'x'` in `'Index'` means that you will also match `'Indexxxxxx :'`.  The `+` after `\s` means there needs to be at least one space.  If you want to match zero or more spaces change the `+` to a `*`.

Note that I used `re.match()` which will only match at the beginning of a string.  If your match can occur anywhere in the string use `re.search()` instead.

Comment: I think you meant `*` instead of `?` for 0 or more :p